# Inverse currying for macros?

Tags: c++, macros

Assume we have a `#define FOO(x,y) something`.

I want to construct such macro `#define BAR` that `BAR(x)(y)` would call `FOO(x,y)`. How can I do it, if it's possible at all?

I tried following:

```
#define BAR(x) FOO(x, BAR_
#define BAR_(y) y)
```

But got:

> ```
> error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "FOO"
> ```

Here's a MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

#define FOO(x,y) std::cout << x << y << '\n';

#define BAR(x) FOO(x, BAR0
#define BAR0(y) y)

#define STR(...) STR0(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STR0(...) #__VA_ARGS__

int main()
{
    std::cout << STR( BAR(1)(2) );
}
```

Another attempt:

```
#define BAR FOO BAR0
#define BAR0(x) (x, BAR1
#define BAR1(y) y)
```

This one compiles, but leaves `FOO (1, 2)` unexpanded in the end.

MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

#define FOO(x,y) std::cout << x << y << '\n';

#define BAR FOO BAR0
#define BAR0(x) (x, BAR1
#define BAR1(y) y)

#define STR(...) STR0(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STR0(...) #__VA_ARGS__

int main()
{
    // Prints `FOO (1, 2)`, but I want `std::cout << 1 << 2 << '\n';`
    std::cout << STR( BAR(1)(2) );
}
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It's simply that one of the macros I have to write would look better as `BAR(some args)(some more args)` rather than with all arguments stuffed into a single pair of parentheses. Of course I could settle for something like `BAR((some args)(some more args))` (which I know how to make), but I wonder if the exact syntax I want is possible. So let's say I'm mostly asking out of academic interest.

Comment: I meant, why write the macros at all? Oh, please don't tell me it is some kind of logger :-(

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm trying to make a simple reflection library, and it occured to me that I can use macros to define class members *and* generate metadata for them at the same time (apparently I like DRY more than I don't like macros). And if I have to use macros, I decided to make them as convenient to use as I can.

Comment: "apparently I like DRY more than I don't like macros" - oh dear. Well, on your head be it.

Comment: Now I have an urge to develop a logging system with tons of macros.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Dissecting the error

Let's start here:

```
#define BAR(x) FOO(x, BAR_
#define BAR_(y) y)
#define FOO(x,y) foo{x|y}
BAR(1)(2)
```

Note that I'm only going to use the preprocessor to debug the preprocessor (why do I need to build C++ programs, which invokes the preprocessor anyway, when I can simply just invoke the preprocessor?  (That's rhetorical o/c; I'm just telling a story here)).

Here's how the CPP looks at this.  We see `BAR`; that's a function-like macro.  Interesting, but not actionable unless we see an open parentheses.  Next, we see... an open parentheses.  Now we're getting somewhere... we need to identify its arguments.  So we keep scanning: `BAR(1)`... there... that's the matching open parentheses... looks like we're invoking with one argument.  `BAR` it turns out is defined with one argument, so this works great.

Now we perform **argument substitution**... so we note that `BAR`'s replacement list mentions its parameter (`x`) in a non-stringifying, non-pasting way.  That means we should evaluate the corresponding argument (`1`), which is easy... that's just itself.  That evaluation result then replaces the parameter in the replacement list, so we have `FOO(1, BAR_`.  We're now done with argument substitution.

The next thing we need to do is **rescan and further replacement**.  So we rescan... `FOO`, ah, yes.  That's a function-like macro... `FOO(` ...and it's being invoked.  Now we're getting somewhere... we need to identify its arguments.  So, we keep scanning: `FOO(1, BAR_(2)`...and, suddenly we reach the end of the file.  Huh?  That's not right.  `FOO` is being invoked; it's supposed to have a matching parentheses.

You might naively think that `BAR_(2)` should be invoked, but that's not how macros work.  They evaluate outer-in, and the "in" (aka, argument tokens) *only* evaluates if there's a mention of the parameter in the replacement list, where said mention is not a stringification or paste.

Note that if `FOO` were not a function-like macro, this story would go an entirely different direction.  In such a case, `FOO(` would simply be tokens the preprocessor doesn't care about... so by the time it sees `BAR_(2)`, it *will* be invoking a macro.  But there's another "cheat"; if `FOO` is passed over without actually invoking the macro `FOO`, the tokens would *also* be skipped over.  In both cases, `FOO(1, 2)` will eventually be produced, which is what you want.  But if you then want to *evaluate* `FOO` as a function-like macro, you have only one choice.  You need a second pass; first pass actually allows your second argument in the sequence to be invoked to build your macro, and this pass *must not* allow `FOO` to be invoked.  The *second* pass is needed to invoke it.

## 2. How to do this

Well, that's easy enough:

```
#define DELAY()
#define BAR(x) FOO DELAY() (x, BAR_
#define BAR_(y) y)
#define FOO(x,y) foo{x|y}
#define EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__
BAR(1)(2)
EVAL(BAR(1)(2))
```

Here's how this is different (first line).  After `BAR`'s argument substitution, its replacement list is now `FOO DELAY() (1, BAR_` instead of just `FOO(1, BAR_`.  Now, during the rescan, it still sees `FOO`, which is still interesting... but the next token it sees is `DELAY`, not an open parentheses.  So the CPP in this pass decides it's *not* invoking `FOO` and passes on it.  After the full `DELAY()` expansion, which produces nothing, it then just sees `(1, BAR_`; the first three are just tokens.  `BAR_`, however, is a macro invocation, and so goes the story... so the result of expanding `BAR(1)(2)` is to produce the tokens `FOO(1, 2)`, error free.  But that doesn't evaluate `FOO`.

The `EVAL`, however, accepts `BAR(1)(2)` as an argument.  Its replacement list mentions its "parameter" (varying arg variant), so `BAR(1)(2)` is fully evaluated, producing `FOO(1, 2)`.  Then `FOO(1, 2)` is rescanned, which is when `FOO` actually gets invoked.

Comment: Your solution is basically no different from the second snippet in the question, since both only work with `EVAL`. This is not quite what I'm looking for, since all this is done to make the macro calls as terse as possible; if I'm going to go with `EVAL(BAR(1)(2))`, I might as well shorten it to `BAR((1)(2))` (which isn't that hard).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm confused.  Are you asking me for `#define MYBAR(x) EVAL(BAR x)`?  The main point of my post is that you can't do `BAR(1)(2)`; that you need at least two passes (and that this does work).  I don't know your design constraints, but if `MYBAR((1)(2))` works for you, I agree... it certainly can work.

Comment: I was trying to say that I already know how to do `BAR((1)(2))`, and since the reason I wanted to have `BAR(1)(2)` is to have even more terse call syntax (see comments under the question), `EVAL(BAR(1)(2))` is of little use to me, since it's even less terse than `BAR((1)(2))`.

Comment: Also I'm saying that your solution has the same effect as the second snippet in the question, except it has `EVAL` added. *"main point of my post is that you can't do `BAR(1)(2);`"* I must say the big "How to do this" caption was a bit misleading for me at first. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, I see now... sorry for the confusing caption.