# Is it possible to write a macro that takes two pairs of parentheses and transform it to a single macro call?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I wonder if it’s possible to write a macro that works as follows:

```
A(a, b, c)(1, 2)
```

Where each set of parentheses actually takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

I’d like to pass each argument list as one parameter to another macro `B`. My goal is that the above is transformed to:

```
B((a, b, c), (1, 2))
```

And then `B` should be evaluated of course.

I’ve tried to do the following:

```
#define HELPER(...) __VA_ARGS__))
#define A(...) B((__VA_ARGS__), (HELPER
```

This evaluates exactly to the `B` expression above, but as soon as I try to define the macro `B`, the preprocessor will give me an error: `unterminated macro argument list invoking macro "B"`

I think the following is happening: At first we replace `A(a, b, c)`. This leads us to `B((a, b, c), (HELPER`. Then the result of this replacement is scanned again and we find the macro `B`. But within this replacement result that is currently being scanned, the macro call to `B` doesn’t terminate. The preprocessor doesn’t look ahead in this situation and therefore gives us an error.

Right now I think what I’m trying to achieve is not possible. Is that right? Or am I missing something and this can actually be done?

**Edit:**
To provide some context: I’m trying to improve an exception-less error handling macro that is similar to boost’s `BOOST_OUTCOME_TRY`. It is used like this:

```
TRY(const auto [a, b], parsePair(myString));
```

It takes 2+ argurments (three in this case) to support structured bindings. Now, I would like to add the option to provide additional context (in `fmt::format` style) to the error while we pass it up the stack. I’ve found a way to make the following syntax work:

```
TRY(const auto [a, b], parsePair(myString), CTX("my context: {}", myCfgPath));
```

This works fine, but requires an additional macro `CTX` that the user needs to remember. So I was wondering if I could support a different syntax like:

```
TRY(const auto [a, b], parsePair(myString))("my context: {}", myCfgPath);
```

Unfortunately, it seems that this is not possible. If you have any other suggestions on how to improve the syntax, please let me know.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I am certain that without macros it becomes so much simpler.

Comment: Looks like a XY problem,  and no that's not possible with a preprocessor macro alone to get that syntax compiled.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Inverse currying for macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51689584/2752075). I've been looking for this for some time too, and no, it seems there is no way. Unless, of course, the entire thing is passed as a parameter to another macro invocation, in which case it becomes more or less simple.

Comment: not sure how to best deal with such question. If you tag `c++` you will always face comments suggesting that you should not use a macro. The need for the preprocessor is steadily converging to 0 in modern c++. If you remove the `c++` tag you will have less readers, but ihmo it would set the right frame for this question as it currently stands. Or you might want to tell us about the actual use case

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I would like to not go further into the actual problem I’m trying to solve. I have no doubts at all that what I’m working on can’t be done without macros, not even in C++23 (and I need a solution that works in C++17).

A solution to this question would give me a nicer syntax for my actual problem, for which I already have a solution.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This seems to be a duplicate of the linked question indeed. And the answer is pretty much what I had also guessed. `EVAL` is not an option in my case unfortunately, as the net result would be a worse syntax then what I currently have...

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Perhaps we could suggest a nicer macro syntax, at least.

Comment: With a variadic template class and a variadic template `operator()`, you could easily have the `A(...)(...)` syntax. Maybe store the parameter pack of `A` constructor into a `std::tuple` so that you can reuse it in the `A::operator()(...)` definition.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added context to my question. Please let me know if you have any ideas for improvement.

Comment: @Fareanor I’m aware of this possibility, thanks. Unfortunately, as I stated above, this problem cannot be solved without using the preprocessor.

Comment: I did it without using preprocessor macros [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8zv9z75oq). I used `std::tuple`s under the hood for the substitutions.

Comment: @Fareanor I know this is possible, thanks. But it won’t help me with my actual problem. I  need the preprocessor, please trust me on this :)